# Scraping specific elements from page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python, and I was looking into using scrapy to scrape specific elements on a page.

I need to fetch the Name and phone number listed on a members page.

This script will fetch the entire page, what can I add/change to fetch only those specific elements?

```
    import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["fali.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.fali.org/members/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/?id=")[-2] + '%random%'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Nothing yet, I have no Idea how to go about it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow! This QA site is there to answer very specific questions about coding, it is not a replacement for a 101 class for python coding. You might want to read [scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and [python for beginners](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) page to start with. You'll be warmly welcomed as soon as you have a specific problem to solve for which you'll need help!

Comment: I have completely rephrased the question.  Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a page:
http://www.fali.org/members/

instead it redirects to the home page.

That makes it impossible to give specifics.

Here is an example:

```
    article_title = response.xpath("//td[@id='HpWelcome']/h2/text()").extract()
```

That parses "Florida Association of Licensed Investigators (FALI)" from their homepage.You can get browser plugins to help you figure out xpaths. XPath Helper on chrome makes it easy.

That said -- go through the tutorials posted above. Because you are gonna have more questions I'm sure and broad questions like this aren't taken well on stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As shark3y states [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31846793/3941341) the `start_url` gets redirected to the main page.

If you have read the documentation you should know that Scrapy starts scraping from the `start_url` and it does not know what you want to achieve.

In your case you need to start from `http://www.fali.org/search/newsearch.asp` which returns the search results for all members. Now you can set-up a `Rule` to go through the result list and call a `parse_detail` method for every member found and follow the links through the result pagination.

In the `parse_detail` method you can go through the site of the member and extract every information you need. I guess you do not need the whole site as you do in your example in your question because it would generate a lot of data on your computer -- and at the end you have to parse it anyway.

Comment: I think I get it, is it possible you can give a code example?  Just a basic script to show how I can do it, I am still learning python.